# FormsAuthenticationTicket is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Using Framework 4.0

Scenario 1:
   Signed in using Live.com.
   In Live.com FormsAuthenticationTicket is not null & ticket.name is my UserID.
   In Local.com FormsAuthenticationTicket is null.
   I dont know what goes missing here.

Scenario 2:
   Signed in using Local.com.
   In Local.com FormsAuthenticationTicket is not null & ticket.name is my UserID.
   In Live.com FormsAuthenticationTicket is null.

My Machine config settings is same in Local & Live sites
Target Framework is 4.0

ApplicationAuthenticate_request is below:

```
HttpCookie AuthCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = null;
if (AuthCookie != null)
{
    try
    {
        ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(AuthCookie.Value);
        if (ticket != null && ticket.Name != null)
            Response.Write(ticket.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex11)
    {
        string sErr = ex11.Message + ex11.StackTrace;
    }
}
```

Signin code is below

```
authenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(UserId, mPersistant, 30);
//FormsAuthenticationTicket authenticationTicketV1 = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userGuid,DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), lPersistant, "User");
string authEncrypt = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket);
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTickChk = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authEncrypt);
bool bChk = authTickChk.Name.Equals(authenticationTicket.Name);
// Create form identity from FormsAuthenticationTicket.
id = new FormsIdentity(authenticationTicket);
// Set the Context User
HttpContext.Current.User = this;
```

Answer (score 1):

By machine.config do you mean web.config? This could be the issue if your web.config files are different

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
  cookieless="UseCookies"
  domain="contoso.com" />
</authentication>
```

Your browser will only submit the FormsAuth cookie to the domain specified in the web.config file, perhaps you have this set to different domains in each environment?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the forms authentication cookie is not being sent to a different site, which is expected behavior.  The thing to realize is that forms authentication is just a cookie with an encrypted value being passed around.  The forms authentication ticket still obeys all the rules of cookies, which include the rule that a cookie set by one site (live.com) will never be sent to a different site (local.com).

Also, I suggest that you use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` to log in your user. The login code doesn't appear to set a cookie.

A tool such as Fiddler might help clear things up for you.  When you login, the response should contain a header that looks something like `Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=FC0C57A...; path=/; HttpOnly`

Each subsequent request will send a header that looks something like `Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=zcsmunozu0iqshwcvb11qu1m; .ASPXAUTH=FC0C57A...`

However, your browser will only send the .ASPXAUTH cookie if the domain is the same as the site that set the cookie.